# clearfix remove indent for first slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a slider using `sly`, `jqueryui` and stuff, and I had a problem with the `clearfix` class, which for the first slide indents to the right by 32 pixels

And in general, after this slider, then the rest of the layout seems to break a little

I checked all the connections, but I still can't figure out why this is happening, I need to remove this padding at the beginning

What could be the problem?

```js
$(function () {
    mainSly.init();
});

let commonSly = {
    onChange: function (eventName, sly) {
        let duration = eventName !== 'load' ? 400 : 0,
            $prevElms = $(sly.options.prevPage).add(sly.options.prev),
            $nextElms = $(sly.options.nextPage).add(sly.options.next);

        if (sly.pos.dest <= sly.pos.start) {
            $prevElms.fadeOut(duration);
        } else {
            $prevElms.fadeIn(duration);
        }

        if (sly.pos.dest >= sly.pos.end) {
            $nextElms.fadeOut(duration);
        } else {
            $nextElms.fadeIn(duration);
        }
    }
};

let mainSly = {
    frame: null,
    wrap: null,
    sly: null,
    init: function () {
        let _self = this;
        _self.frame = $('.main-slider .frame');
        _self.wrap = _self.frame.parent();

        _self.initSly();

        _self.resize();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            _self.resize();
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            _self.resize();
        }, 3000);
    },
    resize: function () {
        let _self = this;
        let k = 1;
        let w = $(".main-slider .frame").width() / k;
        let li = $(".main-slider .frame ul li");
        li.width(w);
        _self.sly.reload();
        $(".main-slider .frame ul").width(w * li.length);
    },
    initSly: function () {
        let _self = this;
        _self.sly = new Sly(_self.frame, {
            horizontal: 1,
            itemNav: 'basic',
            smart: 1,
            activateOn: 'click',
            mouseDragging: 1,
            touchDragging: 1,
            releaseSwing: 1,
            startAt: 0,
            scrollBar: null,
            pagesBar: null,
            activatePageOn: 'click',
            speed: 300,
            elasticBounds: 1,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            dragHandle: 1,
            dynamicHandle: 1,
            clickBar: 1,
            scrollBy: 0,

            // Cycling
            cycleBy: 'pages',
            cycleInterval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: 1,
            //startPaused: 1,

            // Buttons
            prevPage: _self.wrap.find('.left'),
            nextPage: _self.wrap.find('.right'),
        }).init();
        //
        _self.sly.on('load change', function (eventName) {
            commonSly.onChange(eventName, this);
        });

        _self.sly.one('load', function () {
            $(".main-slider").css("opacity", 1)
        });
    },
}
```

```css
.fixed {
  max-width:1350px;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.week-wrap {
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider {
  clear:both;
  margin:-20px 0 0;
  opacity:0;
}
.main-slider .frame.horizontal ul {
  display:block;
}
.main-slider .frame.horizontal ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  border-radius:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#333 none no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider li img {
  opacity:0;
 }
.main-slider li .info .h2 {
  color:#fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:4px 0 0;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:36px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  float:left;
}
.main-slider li .info a {
  float:right;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav {
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left, .main-slider .main-slider-nav .right {
  position:relative;
  top:-320px;
  width:40px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left {
  float:left;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .right {
  float:right;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left i,
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .right i {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sly/1.6.1/sly.min.js" integrity="sha512-uR46GOwRUepFi2dzcatO3qpr4onAj46VC9ltPFIwaX8YXl5O18nVT/JnJZY7yqrrKUP0ngD/YjuatsJqCDpYyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="week-wrap main-slider">
    <div class="frame horizontal" id="basic">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="it active" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 1">
            </li>
            <li class="it" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 2">
            </li>
            <li class="it" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 3">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-slider-nav">
        <div class="fixed">
            <a href="#" class="left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `padding`, I recommend starting your styles with this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    mainSly.init();
});

let commonSly = {
    onChange: function (eventName, sly) {
        let duration = eventName !== 'load' ? 400 : 0,
            $prevElms = $(sly.options.prevPage).add(sly.options.prev),
            $nextElms = $(sly.options.nextPage).add(sly.options.next);

        if (sly.pos.dest <= sly.pos.start) {
            $prevElms.fadeOut(duration);
        } else {
            $prevElms.fadeIn(duration);
        }

        if (sly.pos.dest >= sly.pos.end) {
            $nextElms.fadeOut(duration);
        } else {
            $nextElms.fadeIn(duration);
        }
    }
};

let mainSly = {
    frame: null,
    wrap: null,
    sly: null,
    init: function () {
        let _self = this;
        _self.frame = $('.main-slider .frame');
        _self.wrap = _self.frame.parent();

        _self.initSly();

        _self.resize();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            _self.resize();
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            _self.resize();
        }, 3000);
    },
    resize: function () {
        let _self = this;
        let k = 1;
        let w = $(".main-slider .frame").width() / k;
        let li = $(".main-slider .frame ul li");
        li.width(w);
        _self.sly.reload();
        $(".main-slider .frame ul").width(w * li.length);
    },
    initSly: function () {
        let _self = this;
        _self.sly = new Sly(_self.frame, {
            horizontal: 1,
            itemNav: 'basic',
            smart: 1,
            activateOn: 'click',
            mouseDragging: 1,
            touchDragging: 1,
            releaseSwing: 1,
            startAt: 0,
            scrollBar: null,
            pagesBar: null,
            activatePageOn: 'click',
            speed: 300,
            elasticBounds: 1,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            dragHandle: 1,
            dynamicHandle: 1,
            clickBar: 1,
            scrollBy: 0,

            // Cycling
            cycleBy: 'pages',
            cycleInterval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: 1,
            //startPaused: 1,

            // Buttons
            prevPage: _self.wrap.find('.left'),
            nextPage: _self.wrap.find('.right'),
        }).init();
        //
        _self.sly.on('load change', function (eventName) {
            commonSly.onChange(eventName, this);
        });

        _self.sly.one('load', function () {
            $(".main-slider").css("opacity", 1)
        });
    },
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixed {
  max-width:1350px;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.week-wrap {
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider {
  opacity:0;
}
.main-slider .frame.horizontal ul {
  display:flow-root;
}
.main-slider .frame.horizontal ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  border-radius:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#333 none no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider li img {
  opacity:0;
  display: block;
 }
.main-slider li .info .h2 {
  color:#fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:4px 0 0;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:36px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  float:left;
}
.main-slider li .info a {
  float:right;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav {
  position:relative;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left, .main-slider .main-slider-nav .right {
  position:relative;
  top:-320px;
  width:40px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left {
  float:left;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .right {
  float:right;
}
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .left i,
.main-slider .main-slider-nav .right i {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sly/1.6.1/sly.min.js" integrity="sha512-uR46GOwRUepFi2dzcatO3qpr4onAj46VC9ltPFIwaX8YXl5O18nVT/JnJZY7yqrrKUP0ngD/YjuatsJqCDpYyg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="week-wrap main-slider">
    <div class="frame horizontal" id="basic">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="it active" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 1">
            </li>
            <li class="it" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 2">
            </li>
            <li class="it" style="background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg');">
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="fixed">
                        <div class="h2">Test 3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bXta78n.jpg" alt="Test 3">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-slider-nav">
        <div class="fixed">
            <a href="#" class="left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```